# Random Number Change With Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

My Joda Time is changing a number from 9 to 1 in my code.

Code:

```
String name = getFileName();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));

DateTime firstDate = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMDD");
String date = dtf.print(firstDate);
System.out.println(date);

String fake;
while ((fake = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String [] holder = fake.split(" ");

    firstDate = dtf.parseDateTime(holder[2]);
    System.out.println(holder[2]);
    System.out.println(firstDate);
    String useFirstDate = dtf.print(firstDate);
    System.out.println(useFirstDate);
    System.out.println("here");
    break;
}
```

Output:

```
Please input File Name
futuresmin
201306172 //System.out.println(date);
19870901  //System.out.println(holder[2]);
1987-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00 //System.out.println(firstDate);
19870101  //System.out.println(useFirstDate);
here  //System.out.println("here");
```

I do not know if this is a common issue, or if it is just me, yet I have not found anything on the internet regarding this issue.  Why would Joda Time change 19870901 to 19870101?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"DD" is day of *year*, not day of *month*, which is "dd". [Your format string is incorrect](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

---

On an unrelated note, it's difficult to correlate your output with your code. In general, it's best to keep the noise to a minimum, and make it *explicit* which output line comes from which code, like with a header.

Comment: And a link to the API for completeness (and because I'm proud I had this in my bookmarks before coming across this question): [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)